# rounding up to the next whole integer and adding days onto a fixed date - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a result from a simple formula of `"1.46"`. I require part of a formula to round the 1.46 to the next integer, for this example it would become `"2.00"`.

I have a fixed date lets say `"23/07/2014"`, If the previous example stated how many days would need to added onto the fixed date, how would I go about this?

I have tried to keep it as simple as possible to give clarity of what I require. If you need any more information, please ask.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first one you can use `Round` function.

I didn't get the second requirement... any example will be useful

Edit------------------------------------------------------------

Let the `round` value is stored in a variable `Store`. Use below function to add that to date.

```
DateAdd("d", Store, <<Datefieldhere>>)
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the Round function. if the answer rounds to "1.00", is it possible to add "1" days to "23/07/2014"?